# What is meaning of last week?

Tags: word-usage

I wanna say 4th week of the month.

But if I use "last week", that means the past week. Right ?

How to express real Last weekdays

Comment: Putting aside the fact that most months have at least *some* part of a ***fifth*** week, are you asking how to distinguish between article-less ***last week*** (relative to "time of utterance", means *the week preceding the current one*) and ***the last week** of October*? If so, it's usually obvious from context (and the presence or absence of the article), but in some contexts you might want to refer to *the **final** week in October*.

Answer (score 1):

If you *want to* say the fourth week of the month then the best way is

> the fourth week of the month.

Note that even here there is some ambiguity, if the month starts on Wednesday, is the first week 1st-4th of the month, or is it Wednesday 1st to Tuesday 7th? Or does the first week start on Sunday the fifth, or even on Monday the 6th?

Now, what do you mean by the last week?  is it the last seven days, or the last full week? Or the last partial week?  (and while we are looking for ambiguities, if you are in a country that uses a different calendar, do you mean the Islamic month, or the chinese lunar month, or the Western Jan/Feb/Mar month?)

Or do you intentionally mean it to be imprecise and just mean "towards the end of the month"

---

Anyway if you say "the last week in October" or "The last week of the month" You don't mean the previous week, you mean the "final week"

> In the last week of each month we have programming workshop and a series of maths tests.

(In this example it is intentionally imprecise)

> On Monday to Friday of the final full week of each month, each cadet must present himself or herself to their C/O for inspection at 0900 hours. Failure to do so will result in disciplinary action.

(This is unambiguous.)

It is worth pointing out that, for example,

> the last Wednesday of every month

is precise and non-ambiguous

Comment: However, it is worth pointing out (since OP asks about "last weekdays") that, for example, "the last Wednesday of every month" is precise and non-ambiguous, and a lot cleaner than "the fourth Wednesday of every month except when the month has five Wednesdays in it, in which case it will be the fifth Wednesday."

Answer (score 1):

"last week" does indeed mean "the week before this one".

What you do is say "the last week", but then you need to specify what of, that is: "the last week of November" or whenever.

"I finished it last week" means "I finished it in during week before the one we are in today".

"I finished it the last week" would be understood as meaning "I finished it during the final week" -- but without context, the hearer would not know what it is the last week of. Term? The month (but which month)? The year?

Same applies to weekdays:

"I finished it last Wednesday" means "I finished it on Wednesday last week".

"I finished it the last Wednesday" would not be understood, and feels wrong.

"I finished it on the last Wednesday (of whatever)" would be understood unambiguously. Note the use of "on".